# Что случилось с IDEA после обновления?

Tags: android, java, intellij-idea

Что хочет от меня этот IDEA, как сбросить R id?

[image: asd]

Comment: попробовать сделать ребилд с предварительной очисткой?

Comment: Конечно, вот как раз таки на Реболде и срабатывает эта фигня, иногда если Run делать то 1 из 3-4 раз прокатывает, но стоит в коде изменить что - то и нажать Run, опять эта фигня..

На это ругается еще import com.exampe.Poet.R;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая же история, бахаю bin и gen и работает

Comment: @katso, Создал вопрос, думаю, ответят, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136047#

Короче, это после обновы что-то разрабы напортачили, там еще 2 темы такие есть... посмотрим, что ответят

Comment: ВСЕ ВСЕ ВСЕ, У КОГО ГЛЮК ТАКОЙ ЖЕ!!!!!!!!! УДАЛИТЕ К ЧЕРТЯМ ЭТОТ 14.03. СТАВТЕ 13 ВЕРСИЮ, И ВСЕ БУДЕТ ЧИКИ ПУКИ!

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте все депенденсы, могли какие-то отвалиться (хотя это мало вероятно). Проверьте версию developer tools и свои layout-ы, т.к. R-файл может не генерироваться, только в случае ошибки в верстке. Возможно проблема в кастомных вьюхах.

Comment: @Nuclominus, У меня в одном xml активити название View "img_back", ав другом тоже самое, может из за этого?

Как проверить депендесы

Comment: @Futurama Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S или File->Project Structure, с левой стороны будет раздел Modules, выбираешь свой проект и во вкладке Dependencies поверяешь, подключены ли все твои либы. А названия лучше поменяй, обычно используют класс-тег. Например: активити - FirstActionActivity, то layout-е TextView - @+id/tVFATitle (где FA - FirstAction). И так со всеми элементами данного layout-а.

Comment: @Nuclominus, В Депендесе нет ничего, кроме моего проекта, я все стандартными делаю. У этого проекта нет левых библиотек.

Comment: @Nuclominus, Все бестолку, короче((. У него где-то сохранились id старых названий... img_asd нет у меня, а в поле выбора есть...

Comment: @Nuclominus, а одиннаковыми именами view в layout  можно называть?

Comment: в одном и том же layout имена точно должны быть разные.